# Assembly malloc a stack array

Tags: arrays, assembly, stack, malloc

I am mixing C and assembly and I am sending this to assembly:

```
extern int Fill(int** arr, int n);
```

How can I dynamically allocate array in size n, (which should be later in the **arr) and fill the array with number 1. (Model small, .386)

In case failure of allocating it return 0. otherwise it just allocate it and stick it to [bp+4] and fill it with number 1.

Comment: Please supply a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) illustrating your problem. But if the C calling code knows `n`, why can't you do the `malloc` before calling the assembler, and pass the single `*` pointer instead? And why are you using "small" model in the 21st century?

Comment: `malloc` + `memset`, should be as easy as that.

Comment: Man Thats my project, I want the model small and to do the malloc in assembly. If you are able to help me please do, if not dont give me other choice. All i want to do do a malloc in assembly I have the **arr and the size n. i want to do malloc to arr in assembly in size n and fill it with 1.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what OS or what compiler you're using.

For 386, small and flat models should be the same. If it's an option, you may want to use .model small,c or .model flat,c so that you don't have to prefix names with _, depending on compiler and assembler.

Assuming standard calling convention with frame pointers (ebp gets pushed onto stack):

```
        mov     eax,12[ebp]          ;n
        push    eax
        call    malloc               ;or maybe _malloc
        add     esp,4
```

If using fastcall, then the first two parameters are in registers. Which registers depends on OS / compiler.

If you get stuck, write the code in C or C++, then have the compiler output assembly code so you see the names and how functions are called.

Answer (score 0):

"malloc a stack array"?  stack allocation is the opposite kind of allocation from malloc.  It's fast, but freed when your function returns.

If you need to allocate memory that will be returned to the caller, you need to use malloc (i.e. make a function call to the `malloc` library function).

Or if the code you're passing this pointer to is not going to `free(3)` it, you could use `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS)` directly.

Fill it using `rep stosd` to store 32bit (dword) integers.  (Or, if you care about performance for old CPUs with slow `rep stosd` (AMD pre-Bulldozer), use SSE vector stores.)  See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) wiki for lots of useful links.

Comment: No you didnt understand what I need. The array in the stack yes because the function in C sent it. and its been ent like this **Arr. so All i want to do is allocate a place for it and fill it. so I can paste it elements back in C.

Comment: `int Fill(int** arr, int n);` is the C prototype for your asm function, right?  You want the asm function to do  `*arr = malloc(n)`, write to the array, and then return?  Everything I said after the first paragraph applies.

Comment: Yes buddy thats right, and I did, I have this in asm : EXTRN _malloc : NEAR and I push the value I want then do malloc, but im not getting the adress in ax for some reasons...

Comment: @Dang3ry: are you using a 16bit library?  If you call a 32bit malloc, the address will be in `eax`, and almost certainly have bits set in the high 16.

Comment: I did check in the debugger i followed the registers and no, AX and EAX have same value